# Column having no values gives the error 'can not infer schema' while reading excel to dataframe using koalas read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pyspark, databricks, spark-koalas

While reading excel file as dataframe using databricks koalas read_excel() with dtype as **str**, if a column is not having values it gives the error

> can not infer schema from empty dataset

How to solve this issue?
If I change the dtype to **None**, it will not throw error. But numeric data will be read in scientific form.

I tried writing converter:

```
converters={i : (lambda x: str(x) if x or x!='' else np.NaN) for i in range(col_count)}
```

(dtype=str is not working with converter, so removed).
But this will read the string 'NA' as null.
I want the data as it is in the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved with the parameters **dtype=str** and **na_filter = False** while calling **read_excel()**